# Is it possible to use 2 javascript libraries on the same page?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have 2 javascript libraries that I want to combine in one page, is that possible:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jPaginate.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#content").jPaginate();                       
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="pic/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pic/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Why? Try to find a component that works fine for both cases.

Comment: I did try the code and also after removing one jquery it's still not working together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you don't take precautions, the second inclusion might overwrite the first one though.

For jQuery, there is [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Especially have a look at the example which loads two different jQuery versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many scripts as you want, in theory. However, you appear to be including jQuery twice, which is not good. If you have it once, you don't need it again. Also, in general you need to make sure those scripts don't interfere with each other. Usually jQuery plugins are good about that.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. You can have as many scripts you like in a page. Even using the `ready` event twice works, as jQuery can handle multiple event handlers for the same event.

However you are inlcuding jQuery twice, you should only include it once.

If you were using different versions of jQuery, in most cases you can just use the later version. In some cases a script only works with a specific version of jQuery. If both your scripts require a specific version, and they require different versions, then it may be tricky to use them both.